# How do I add Xamarin Forms to an existing UWP XAML app?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml

I have an existing UWP XAML app that I want to add Xamarin Forms to so I can provide my solution on Android and iOS. What is the best way to go about that?  Could somebody point me to a video or something?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that. Xamarin is a different framework. You can not just add support for Xamarin forms and make it work. The strategy for you should be to figure out what code can be used as shared code and create a PCL for it and access that in Xamarin.android app or Xamarin.Forms app with PCL.

If you don't have a lot of code in your app, then probably better would be to start a new Xamarin project and since there are multiple types of Xamarin code sharing strategies and UI strategies, you'd have to figure out which one works best for you and then build an app that runs on all 3 platforms.